# How can I Add and Delete nested Object in array in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[heres my output Image html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHb9P.png) How can I delete Object in array and push when adding some Data

```
angular.module('myApp.Tree_Service', [])
    .factory('TreeService', function() {
        var svc = {};
        var treeDirectories = [
          {
            name: 'Project1',
            id: "1",
            type: 'folder',
            collapse: true,
            children: [
              {
                name: 'CSS',
                id: "1-1",
                type: 'folder',
                collapse: false,
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'style1.css',
                    id: "1-1-1",
                    type: 'file'
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'style2.css',
                    id: "1-1-2",
                    type: 'file'
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ];

          svc.add = function () {}
          svc.delete = function (item, index) { }

          svc.getItem = function () { return treeDirectories; }
        return svc;
    });
})();
```

I'm Newbee in Angularjs and I don't know how much to play it.
Hopefully someone can help me. Im Stucked.

Comment: where you want to push(at what level in treeDirectories)

Comment: Anywhere even as he create. you can see my image output

Answer (score 0):

Well you can delete any object by just using`delete Objname.property`

So for example you want to delete Children in treeDirectories first index object you can use `delete treeDirectories[0].children` if you want to delete children inside children then `delete treeDirectories[0].children[0].children`

if you want to remove an index from an array in lowest level children then

```
treeDirectories[0].children[0].children.splice(index,1)
```

for pushing data is for object you can directly assign value to the property you want

```
  treeDirectories[0].children[0].newproperty = "check"
```

And for array you can

```
treeDirectories[0].children[0].children.push(object)
```

Comment: What if I have too many nested list and i need to delete the object dynamically not static